# gwt rpc serialize generic class

Tags: gwt, rpc, gwt-rpc

I need to pass a class object through the gwt rpc connection as a generic but it seems that rpc does not cooperate with it. The class is serialized using the java.io.Serializable. I have checked it using the gwt IsSerializable but i still have the error.

Here is my code

MySource.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@PersistenceCapable
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.SUBCLASS_TABLE)
public abstract class MySource implements Serializable {
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Persistent
private String userId;
@Persistent
private String title;
@Persistent
private String description;
@Persistent
private String blobKey;
@Persistent
private String youtubeLink;
@Persistent
private String personalLink;
@Persistent
private Date submitedDate;
@Persistent
private float price;


public float getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(float price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getBlobKey() {
    return blobKey;
}

public void setBlobKey(String blobKey) {
    this.blobKey = blobKey;
}

public String getYoutubeLink() {
    return youtubeLink;
}

public void setYoutubeLink(String youtubeLink) {
    this.youtubeLink = youtubeLink;
}

public String getPersonalLink() {
    return personalLink;
}

public void setPersonalLink(String personalLink) {
    this.personalLink = personalLink;
}

public Date getSubmitedDate() {
    return submitedDate;
}

public void setSubmitedDate(Date submitedDate) {
    this.submitedDate = submitedDate;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

}
```

AndroidSource.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@PersistenceCapable
public class AndroidSource extends MySource{

public AndroidSource() {
    super();
}

}
```

CategoryBrowseService.java which is the remoteservice model

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("categoryService")
public interface CategoryBrowseService extends RemoteService{


ArrayList<MySource> getSourceList(Class<? extends MySource> classType); 
}
```

CategoryBrowseServiceAsync.java
    public interface CategoryBrowseServiceAsync {

```
void getSourceList(Class<? extends MySource> classType,
        AsyncCallback<ArrayList<MySource>> callback);

}
```

CategoryBrowsePresenter.java where the rpc is called

```
private void retrieveSources(Class<? extends MySource> classType) {
    CategoryBrowseServiceAsync rpcService =   GWT.create(CategoryBrowseService.class);

    rpcService.getSourceList(classType, new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<MySource>>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            Window.alert("Ooops!!!Sorry!Something went wrong.I am still beta!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<MySource> result) {
            sourceList = result;
            display.setSourceContent(sourceList);
        }
    });
}
```

CategoryBrowseServiceImpl.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CategoryBrowseServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements CategoryBrowseService{

  private SourceDatastore dataStore;


  public CategoryBrowseServiceImpl() {
    dataStore = new SourceDatastore();
  }

  @Override
  public ArrayList<MySource> getSourceList(Class<? extends MySource> classType) {

      return dataStore.getSources(classType);

  }

}
```

Here is the error that i get.

```
Compiling module com.sourcebay.SourceBay
   Scanning for additional dependencies: file:/home/santaris/workspace/SourceBay/src/com/sourcebay/client/presenter/mybay/browse/CategoryBrowsePresenter.java
      Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.sourcebay.client.model.mybay.browse.CategoryBrowseService'
         Rebinding com.sourcebay.client.model.mybay.browse.CategoryBrowseService
            Invoking generator com.google.gwt.user.rebind.rpc.ServiceInterfaceProxyGenerator
               Generating client proxy for remote service interface 'com.sourcebay.client.model.mybay.browse.CategoryBrowseService'
                  [ERROR] java.lang.Class<T> is not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable' or 'java.io.Serializable' nor does it have a custom field serializer (reached via java.lang.Class<? extends com.sourcebay.shared.source.MySource>)
                  [ERROR] java.lang.Class<T> has no available instantiable subtypes. (reached via java.lang.Class<? extends com.sourcebay.shared.source.MySource>)
                     [ERROR]    subtype java.lang.Class<T> is not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable' or 'java.io.Serializable' nor does it have a custom field serializer (reached via java.lang.Class<? extends com.sourcebay.shared.source.MySource>)
   [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/home/santaris/workspace/SourceBay/src/com/sourcebay/client/presenter/mybay/browse/CategoryBrowsePresenter.java'
      [ERROR] Line 75:  Failed to resolve 'com.sourcebay.client.model.mybay.browse.CategoryBrowseService' via deferred binding
```

The paradox is that when i am running my application through the eclipse plugin everything works fine. Could anyone help me please? I have checked to fix the problem through the DTO solution without any success. Moreover i have tried to implement a CustomFieldSerializer as Google suggests without any success too.

Thanks in advance,

Stefanos Antaris

P.S. Sorry for the huge post :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well the problem is that you trying to transport a `Class` object over the network. I have no idea why it is working in dev mode (I've tried it on local project and it failed), but it shouldn't work. You have to use something else instead of `Class` name for example String, which will contain a name of class. Theoretically it can work if you create CustomFieldSerializer for `Class`, but using String instead of Class will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Classes with persistence annotations can work well on the server side, but if you want to pass  its data to the client you must create a plain java serializable class to transport data from server to client.

As noted in the previous answer, persistence annotations are not supported in the client side, as they cannot be translated to equivalent javascript code (and it makes sense since the client doesn't have the responsability of persistence).

Comment: I agree to both of you about the persistence annotations but if i pass the Android object as a java instance and not as a generic it works totally fine. However, if i do not have any persistence annotations to my shared classes how could i store them to the database? Should i use the DTO solution???

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the persistence-related annotations in MySource.java make it implossible to translate to javascript. Try removing the annotations to see if it's related. Also make sure that MySource.java is in a package declared as translatable in the module xml file ("source" element).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `implements Serializable` for defining you class.
I mean like this:

```
    public class AndroidSource extends MySource implements Serializable{

public AndroidSource() {
    super();
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your RPC Services must deal just with Serializable Objects. Domain classes are not translatable to JavaScript So GWT can't send and receive via network (RPC Protocole) such objects. You need to create DTO classes (wich shadows domain class) implementing java.io.Serializable and then reconfigure all your RPC Service to use in input DTOs and output DTOs. Good Luck for your project.